# How to handle business logic errors effectively?

Tags: php, error-handling, business-logic

Let's suppose we have some objects hierarchy built via composition. Is there any pattern to register business logic errors within inner objects and pass them to the upper objects ?

I am just tired of all these *addErrors*, *getErrors* on each level and I feel that I do something incorrectly.

I know about exceptions, but I have no mind how to use them in such case. Business logic error is technically not a critical situation, which should result in interruption of the program execution. Actually interruption is not supposed at all, because we need to register the error and just move on.

*Thanks in advance to share your wisdom and knowledge )*

Small snippet to illustrate the problem:

```
class ErrorContainer {
    private $errors = array();
    function addError($error) { if (!is_array($error)) { $this->errors[] = $error;} else { $this->errors = array_merge($this->errors, $error); } }
    function getErrors() { return $this->errors[]; }
    function hasErrors() { return !empty($this->errors); }
}

class Processor extends ErrorContainer {
    function process($account_id, $orders) {
        $account = new Account();
        if (!$account->loadById($account_id)) { $this->addErrors($account->getErrors);}

        foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
            $order = new Order();
            if (!$order->loadById($order_id)) { $this->addErrors($order->getErrors);}
        }
    }

    return $this->hasErrors();
}

class Account extends ErrorContainer {
    function loadById($account_id) {
        $account = select_from_database($account_id);
        if (!$account) { $this->addError("Account is missing"); }
        if (!$account['active']) { $this->addError("Account is inactive"); }
        // and so on, some checks may add errors in a cycle

        return $this->hasErrors();
    }
}

class Order extends ErrorContainer {} // very similar to Account, but has its own checks

//Usage:

$errors = array();
$items = load_items_from_xml($xml);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $processor = new Processor();
    if (!$processor->process($item['account_id'], $item['orders'])) {
        $errors = array_merge($errors, $processor->getErrors());
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a good question for CodeReview  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions aren't used only in critical situations, but in your case it's not such a bad idea to use the error system you have now. You might consider using constants instead of text for errors, and define all possible error constants in each class.

```
class Account extends ErrorContainer {
    const ERR_ACC_MISSING = 0;
    const ERR_ACC_INACTIVE = 1;
    function loadById($account_id) {
        $account = select_from_database($account_id);
        if (!$account) { $this->addError(ERR_ACC_MISSING); }
        if (!$account['active']) { $this->addError(ERR_ACC_INACTIVE); }
        // and so on, some checks may add errors in a cycle

        return $this->hasErrors();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about constants. I agree it is a right place for them ) As for the main problem - I was hoping that exists some pattern which allows errors to kinda bubble up to the head object. Or maybe pattern that supposes some external container to store/add errors.

Comment: You can't really merge all errors together and handle them at the same time. The same limitation would apply to exception-handling aswell. You need to handle the errors as early as possible.

Comment: What if we have no way (or have no need) to handle the errors, but it is necessary to notify somebody about all errors ? Or errors handling is postponed until some moment, when operator handles them manually ?

Comment: I can think of some solutions. For example, if each constant has a unique value (no class will have identical values), you can merge errors together and postpone errors. Just access the constants in the class scope, eg Account::ERR_ACC_MISSING. Another one is practically the same thing, but make them static variables instead of constants and initialize them to a global function which gives out these unique values. Then you don't have to keep track of the values. I suggest that you post to codereview, maybe they can come up with interesting solutions. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to implement something like that and to use codereview.